# Five-Year plan - defcon suicide?

Tags: twilight-struggle

I'm playing as the USSR in the fantastic Twilight Struggle PC implementation by GMT, and I have a hand of two cards, one is Five-Year Plan, which states:

> USSR Player must randomly discard one card. If the card is a US
>   associated Event, the Event occurs immediately. If the card is a USSR
>   associated Event or an Event applicable to both players, then the card
>   must be discarded without triggering the Event.

and the other is Truman Doctrine:

> Remove all USSR Influence markers in one uncontrolled country in
>   Europe.

When I go to play Five-Year Plan, it gives me the `Defcon Warning`. I'm apparently missing something because I don't understand why playing Five-Year Plan in this situation would allow my opponent to lower Defcon.

Why is this a defcon suicide card?

Answer (score 3):

The USSR might have a card in hand which is a US associated event which automatically lowers defcon, e.g., Duck and Cover.

This answer was for the question as originally stated, which did not specify that the poster was playing as the USSR.

Comment: I should have mentioned in my question that I am playing as the USSR. As such, I know that I don't have a card which is a US associated event which automatically lowers defcon. I was wondering why the games still flashed a defcon warning in this scenario. Perhaps it just flashes defcon warning whenever you play Five-Year plan.

Comment: Your "perhaps" is correct.  The game doesn't explicitly know that defcon suicide will (or even can) happen, it just always warns on cards that could theoretically cause it to happen.

Comment: @bwarner is right; the implementation does not exactly know the circumstances, just the associated cards where the warning *should* flash. For instance, when US play **Ortega elected in Nicaragua**, the game flashes the DEFCON warning, even if the US have no influence in Cuba.